# Xamarin essentials android -connectivity

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using `XamarinEssential` connectivity and I have the following code before running any http call

```
if(Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet 
|| Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.ConstrainedInternet)
{
    // you can make httpcall
}
else
{
    //no connectivity
}
```

Before making the call I disable the wifi from my Android phone and proceed ,however it still says I have Internet when it shouldn't!!

The only way I can make it work is if  I do as follows:

```
var profiles = Connectivity.Profiles.ToList(); 
if(Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet 
||Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.ConstrainedInternet
|| profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi))
{
}
else
{
    //no connectivity
}
```

is the above the correct way to check for connectivity?

It does not seem to work as I expected

many thanks

Comment: Have you turned off cellular data also?

Comment: No I just disabled wifi.Is not that enough ?also my check above seems to catch it. but not sure if correct

Comment: If wifi is off, but cellular data is enabled then the `Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet` statement allows the code to make the http call as you do have internet access. If you only want the data requests to be made when on wifi, then only check that.

Comment: Ok let me summarise networkaccess.internet =Mobile data is on.  Connectionprofile.wifi=WiFi on if contained in profile. So it would make sense to check for both sequentially no?

Comment: If you want the http call to be made if you have *any type* of internet access, then that is all you have to check and you are done, otherwise if you want to restrict it only when the device has wifi, then only check that.

Comment: Put has an answer and I will accept

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for your help I am happy to mark as an answer you helped me with 2 things today that were not clear to me .thanks for your time